# What is the best way to connect two cylinders at a 90 degree angle?

Tags: modeling

I can't seem to find any method to fill this one model. Does anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the edges. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>  or right click or *Edge Menu > Bridge Edge Loops* > add number of cuts and select *Blend Surface*. Adjust *Smoothness* as you wish

Comment: This is awesome method, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can select the Transform pivot to be active vertex and then select the edge loop with the touching vertex as active, extrude and rotate some amount of degrees that you can divide the angle of bend into and just repeat it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
Let's say the bend is 90 degrees so lets make the segment 10 degrees:
[image]

Comment: This is a little bit hard to pull, but the combination with Shift+R button will be useful in many ways. Thanks!